# Non-linear matrix equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B},\mathbf{\mathbf{D}}$ be the regular matrices
$(m,m)$, $\mathbf{C},\mathbf{E},\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Y}$ be the column
vectors $(m,1)$, and $\alpha$ is the positive constant.

Is there any algebraic
solution of the following system of two non-linear matrix equations

\begin{align*}
(\mathbf{A}+\alpha\mathbf{B}\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{Y}^{T}\mathbf{B})\mathbf{X} & =\mathbf{C},\\
(\mathbf{D}+\alpha\mathbf{B}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{B})\mathbf{Y} & =\mathbf{E},
\end{align*}

for the unknown variables $\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Y}$?

I have tried a
simple approach
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{X} & =(\mathbf{A}+\alpha\mathbf{B}\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{Y}^{T}\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{C}.\\
\end{align*}
\
Then,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X} & =[(\mathbf{A}+\alpha\mathbf{B}\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{Y}^{T}\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{C}]^{T}[(\mathbf{A}+\alpha\mathbf{B}\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{Y}^{T}\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{C}],\\
\end{align*}
with the following substitution
\begin{align*}
(\mathbf{D}+\alpha\mathbf{B}[(\mathbf{A}+\alpha\mathbf{B}\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{Y}^{T}\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{C}]^{T}[(\mathbf{A}+\alpha\mathbf{B}\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{Y}^{T}\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{C}]\mathbf{B})\mathbf{Y} & =\mathbf{E}.\\
\end{align*}

The equation might be simplified, but I am not sure how to continue, since the resulting equation for $\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y}$ will be non-linear.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What have you tried? Are there any simple cases on which you can make any progress? E.g., invertibility, normal matrices, commuting matrices, diagonal matrices, etc.?

Comment: @ whpowell96: The only assumption is that A, B, D are symmetric and probably positive-definite.